# Jquery attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a variable (div element) which contains some table html.

I can use this javascript to add a class to each cell that has a background set.

```
  var tds = tempDiv.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
    var oTd = tds[j];

    if (oTd.style.background.length > 0) {
      oTd.className = 'faketh';
      oTd.setAttribute('style', 'Clear');
    } //if
  }//for
```

what i'd like to do is do the same in jquery.  Below is what i've come up with, and the second line works fine, but the first doesn't....

```
  $(tempDiv).find("td[style*='background:']").addClass("faketh");
  $(tempDiv).find("td").removeAttr('style');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: 
Just to add; I'm using the code below without issue.

```
  $(tempDiv).find("tr:odd").addClass('row0');
  $(tempDiv).find("tr:even").addClass("row1");
```

So its not the adding of the class thats the problem... The issue is that i'm not finding any matching elements.  Here is one of the td elements;

```
<td valign="top" class="faketd" style="border: 1pt solid windowtext; padding: 0cm 5.4pt; background: silver none repeat scroll 0% 0%; width: 131.4pt; -moz-background-clip: border; -moz-background-origin: padding; -moz-background-inline-policy: continuous;">
        <p style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt; text-align: justify;"><strong>VPN Name/Description:</strong></p>
        </td>
```

Comment: Do you know what the background is set to or just looking for any value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this using selectors natively in jQuery. The style attribute is not stored as a string by the browser, it's an object.

It has been implemented, however: http://code.google.com/p/aost/wiki/CustomJQuerySelectorInTellurium#:styles

Or you can use $.each in something like [this](http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=157350):

```
$("img").each(function() {
    if($(this).css('background').length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass('faketh');
    }

});
```

Or you can use the jQuery filter:

```
var x = $("#tempDiv td").filter(function(i){
    return $(this).css("background").length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Haven't tested this yet... but its the best answer on here... hopefully will work ;)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(tempDiv).find("td[style*=background]").addClass("faketh");
```

EDIT
to prevent selection of elements that have some kind of "background-" you could also do following

```
$(tempDiv).find("td[style*=background]:not(td[style*=background-])").addClass("faketh");
```

but if an element has both "background:blabla" and "background-color:#FFF", it won't be selected

Comment: Have double checked... an no.  Removing the single quotes does not make a difference. :(

Comment: won't removing the : mean that i'll now match attributes such as background-color etc etc.  I'm just after the background attribute.

Comment: Removed the colon and.... nope. :(
So weird that it doesn't work... looks right to me.

Answer (score 1):

A few warnings:

- The contents of the style selector should be quoted (check the samples in the [Jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeContains#attributevalue)), as you have them in the question, not unquoted as others recommend.
- Be careful with checking the style attribute in jQuery attribute selectors.  The browser may modify the contents of the string (re-ordering, the spacing around the colon, etc.) for it's internal representation, and each browser does this slightly differently.

The most important bit:

- Are you using **Firefox?**  I've had trouble with attribute selectors in Firefox once or twice, so if you've only tested in Firefox, check Chrome/IE/Safari/Opera/etc.  It won't solve the problem, but may give you a different scope for it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what tempDiv is, you should also be able to shorten it up by doing:

```
$(tempDiv + " td[style*=background:]").addClass("faketh");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the string 'background:' but in the example you gave, it's using 'background-color:'

So change it to either:

```
$(tempDiv).find("td[style*=background-color:]").addClass("faketh");
```

or:

```
$(tempDiv).find("td[style*=background]").addClass("faketh");
```

Comment: You are quite correct, my example td html element was incorrect.  I have ammended it.  Some of the td elements do have a background-color attribute, which i don't care about.  I only want to match on background.